# Regex only allow numeric chars plus signs, dot and E

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a TextBox which should only accept numbers (they can be simple `int` or `float` with E as power factor).

So some valid examples are:

```
1
+1.1
0
.1
1E-1
1e-2
-1.66
-6e-10
```

non-valid example:

```
  E-1
```

Generally it should start with either a number or + and - signs or a DOT.

Then I will put this in `TextChanged` event and it will be fine.

```
 textBox.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, @"[\d]", ""); //so useless!
```

Comment: perhaps instead of regex, you could use decimal.TryParse()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your exponents to be used, try this (be sure to add `using System.Globalization;`):

```
decimal value;
if(Decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out value))
{
    textBox.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: this is much cleaner if you use `.TryParse()` instead of your own try/catch block

Comment: Ah yes, I couldn't see the overload of `TryParse` which took a `NumberStyles`, but I've spotted it now, will update my answer appropriately :)

Comment: "E" doesn't sound like a valid numeric value to me? What is it you're trying to achieve by entering "E"?

Comment: well some users like to enter `1000000` as `10E6`...I can fix that with a try/catch...but your code looks good I don't want to ruin it :D

Comment: Actually it works, but if textbox is empty and user enters an E it will throw exeption. I fixed it by try/catch. Thakns!

Answer (score 1):

Why use Regex at all?

```
float f;
bool isNumber = Single.TryParse(textbox.Text, out f);
```

Comment: I agree with this solution, constructing a regex with that kind of "can consist of... but only in this order.. and also.." will get convoluted really fast.

Comment: -1 for not actually being correct. The correct overload is the one that supplies an IFormatProvider and more importantly, NumberStyles (in this case, NumberStyles.Float)

Comment: well my heart was in the right place ;) . Lukazoid got it right in the other answer. +1 for him.